# SQL, ignore all values if one of them is marked

Tags: sql, t-sql

i would like to know how to exclude all data points of a certain value if any of them has a certain flag value. ( i have provided the queries at the bottom of this question)

example.
this is my current data in the table (the flag can take on more than 2 values (N,P and A))

```
RevisionID          DateTime            Value  Flag
21026        2017-01-01 06:00:00.000    224.4   N
21026        2017-01-01 07:00:00.000    476.8   P
21026        2017-01-01 08:00:00.000    588.6   N
21027        2017-01-01 07:00:00.000    138.4   N
21027        2017-01-01 08:00:00.000    683.6   N
```

the data above will then be flattened, by highest revision for a given datetime ( i can already do this with the query provided).

the result will look like this

```
RevisionID          DateTime            Value  Flag
21026        2017-01-01 06:00:00.000    224.4   N
21027        2017-01-01 07:00:00.000    138.4   N
21027        2017-01-01 08:00:00.000    683.6   N
```

but what i want to do is, if any of the data points which has the flag P, all associated date times should not be displayed

currently row 2 contains the P flag

```
21026        2017-01-01 07:00:00.000    476.8   P
```

i want the final result to look like this

```
RevisionID          DateTime            Value  Flag
21026        2017-01-01 06:00:00.000    224.4   N
21027        2017-01-01 08:00:00.000    683.6   N
```

below are the queries provided which will flatten the data, now i want to exclude all data points even if one of them is marked as P

```
    CREATE TABLE #data ( RevisionID INT, _datetime DATETIME, _value FLOAT, flag CHAR)
    INSERT INTO #data VALUES 
    (21026,'2017-01-01 06:00:00.000',224.4,'N'),
    (21026,'2017-01-01 07:00:00.000',476.8,'P'),
    (21026,'2017-01-01 08:00:00.000',588.6,'N'),
    (21027,'2017-01-01 07:00:00.000',138.4,'N'),
    (21027,'2017-01-01 08:00:00.000',683.6,'N')

    WITH RNData AS 
    (
        SELECT d.RevisionID, d._datetime, d._value, d.flag, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime ORDER BY d._datetime, d.RevisionID DESC) AS rn 
                  FROM #data d
    )select * from RNData where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions for this as well:

```
WITH d AS (
      SELECT d.RevisionID, d._datetime, d._value, d.flag,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime ORDER BY d.RevisionID DESC) AS seqnum,
             SUM(CASE WHEN d.flag = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime) as cnt_P 
      FROM #data d
     )
SELECT d.* 
FROM d 
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND cnt_P = 0;
```

Note that you should not repeat the partitioning keys in the `ORDER BY`.

If the flag only takes on the values of `'N'` and `'P'`, then you can use a small shortcut:

```
WITH d AS (
      SELECT d.RevisionID, d._datetime, d._value, d.flag,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime ORDER BY d.RevisionID DESC) AS seqnum,
             MAX(d.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime) as max_flag 
      FROM #data d
     )
SELECT d.* 
FROM d 
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND max_flag = 'P';
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. yes the flag can take on more than 2 values (i've updated my question) sorry about missing info

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Both your queries refer to column rn. I think you meant seqnum? Also, wouldn't the second query be <> 'P' instead of = 'P'?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE expression (conditional aggregation):

```
WITH RNData AS 
(
  SELECT 
    d.RevisionID, d._datetime, d._value, d.flag, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime ORDER BY d._datetime, d.RevisionID DESC) AS rn, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime) AS flagged_p
  FROM #data d
)
select * 
from RNData 
where rn = 1
and flagged_p = 0;
```

Comment: Correct; thanks for spotting this. I've added the missing comma.

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
select * 
from 
( SELECT d.RevisionID, d._datetime, d._value, d.flag
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d._datetime ORDER BY d.RevisionID DESC) AS rn 
         FROM #data d 
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #data p WHERE d._datetime = p._datetime and p.flag = 'P') 
         AND d.flag <> 'P' 
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

`AND d.flag <> 'P'` is not required but *might* make it more efficient